# importing a variable from one typescript file into another

Tags: angular, typescript, import

I am attempting to import a variable from one type script file into another.

the variable I want to import is `cityListUrl`

the type script file it is in is coded like this:

```
export class backendUrls{

  // root url
  rooturl:string= 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';

//get a list of all cities
  cityListUrl:string = this.rooturl + '/api/city/';


}
```

the file I want to import it into looks like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {backendUrls} from 'app/backendUrls';

@Injectable()
export class cityGetService{
  constructor(private http: Http){}

  cityGet(){
    this.http.get(backendUrls.cityListUrl)
  }
}
```

the `cityListUrl` in my pycharm editor is currently red. with the message

```
TS2339: 'cityListUrl' does not exist on type 'typeof backendUrls'.
```

has anyone had this issue before? How would I fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to handle server api urls is to use the angular environment files.
There is two advantages to use it:

- Available in all your application
- You can handle multiples platform (localhost, dev, stating, prod) without modifing your code

in `app/environments` you can create differents files:

- environments.prod.ts
- environments.ts
- environement.test.ts

In each files you defines your gobals variables:

for localhost:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiHost: 'http://localhost',
  recaptchaKey: '6LeWzxQUeazeAAPpR0gZFezaeazL5AvUP3moN1U4u',
  fileHost: 'http://file.localhost',
};
```

for prod example:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiHost: 'http://prod',
  recaptchaKey: '6LeWzxQUeazeAAPpR0gZFezaeazL5AvUP3moN1U4u',
  fileHost: 'http://file.prod',
};
```

To use it in your scripts you only need to always import 
`import { environment } from './environments/environment'; //relative path from where your file is`

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment'
export class Service {
    protected cityListUrl = '/api/city/';

    constructor(protected http: Http) { }

    get() {
      this.http.get(environment.apiHost + this.cityListUrl).map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

It's when you build your project with angular-cli, you precise which environment you want to use

`ng build --environment=prod`

or

`ng serve --environment=test`

Which it is cool because you can easly integrate this command line in a continuous integration tools.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to just define and export each variable independently. This way you can also import them independently as well.

```js
export const rooturl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';
export const cityListUrl = rooturl + '/api/city/'
```

And import them this way.

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {cityListUrl} from 'app/backendUrls';

@Injectable()
export class cityGetService{
  constructor(private http: Http){}

  cityGet(){
    this.http.get(cityListUrl)
  }
}
```

If you need them all together in an object just export them like that as well.

```js
export const rooturl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';
export const cityListUrl = rooturl + '/api/city/'

export const all = {
    rooturl, cityListUrl
}
```

The way you have it now it's a class, that must be instantiated in order to get access to it's instance properties.

The generated code for your class looks like this.

```js
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var backendUrls = (function () {
        function backendUrls() {
            // root url
            this.rooturl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';
            //get a list of all cities
            this.cityListUrl = this.rooturl + '/api/city/';
        }
        return backendUrls;
    }());
    exports.backendUrls = backendUrls;
});
```

If you need a class you will first have to make an instance of it using the **new** keyword.

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {backendUrls} from 'app/backendUrls';

@Injectable()
export class cityGetService{
  constructor(private http: Http){}

  cityGet(){
    this.http.get(new backendUrls().cityListUrl)
  }
}
```

If you need to use a class but want to have this in a static manner you can make the properties static then they'll get defined as properties on the class itself instead of an instance.

```js
export class backendUrls {
    // root url
    static rooturl: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';

    // need to use the class to access the root since we don't have an instance.
    static cityListUrl: string = backendUrls.rooturl + '/api/city/';

}
```

Comment: interestingly the ; at the end of each variable is now red with the warning expected , whats going on with that?

Comment: well i have no more errors in the cityGetService.ts file which means your solution worked thank you. Its the silly ; , issue I commented above. I am thinking its just pycharm complaining for no reason. I'll accept your answer and thank you oh your updating yay thank you

Comment: actually the first solution doesn't really work, since this.rootUrl is not defined because does not point to backendUrl. and cityurl will end up as "undefined/api/city/"

Comment: darn ok walk me through sensei

Comment: does this mean I can get rid of the export const backendUrls?  That the only thing I need to have in this file are the two variables with the exports on them?

Comment: yep, you can export them all as part of an object too if you need to have them grouped like that for some reason, I can add an example for that too if you want. :)

Comment: no thank you on that. We are close though. One more wrinkle it seems. I removed the export const backendUrls and just have the export const variables. I removed the this from the rooturl in cityListUrl I now have an error on the rooturl in cityListUrl which says: expected = and expected new line or semicolon very werid

Comment: oops never mind got it forgot to remove the : and add a = its cause im stupid lol